# In_array not working

Tags: php, arrays, xml, simplexml

I have an array, I applied in_array function to find a specific number in that array, but it's showing no result, the data is inside the array but no response..:(

**Array:**

```
 Array
(
[0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [0] => 572140
    )

[1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [0] => 533167
    )

[2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [0] => 572070
    )

[3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [0] => 572383
    )

[4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [0] => 285078
    )

[5] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [0] => 430634
    )
}
```

**CODE I AM USING:**

```
 if(in_array('285078',$arr))
    {
        echo 'yes';
    }
    else
    {
       echo "No";
    }
```

This is the array I am creating from the xml file..

```
 $arr = array();
 foreach($xmlInjury as $data)
 {
  array_push($arr,$data->player_id);
 }
```

It's only showing 'NO'.. please help me on this...

Comment: I think it is because of "object array" coming in between. May be because o fthat it is not working.

Comment: @Khushboo how can i remove that object from array, is there any method??

Comment: You have an array of objects. Loop through them and check whether your value is in them.

Comment: How do you get this array? If you can - change it

Comment: You can't find `'285078'` in the array, because it is **not** in the array. What you have is an array of `SimpleXMLElement` objects.

Comment: can you post your code to convert with xml?

Comment: I am just getting it from a xml file, get the data than saved it in array, can anybody tell how can i get ride of "SimpleXMLElement objects"...??

Comment: *"...  get the data than saved it in array..."* While you're doing that, don't add the `SimpleXMLElement` to the array, but rather the value that it presents.

Comment: I have edit the question with the code from where i am converting xml into array..

Comment: without knowing your xml and require code no one can exactly help you?

Comment: I have to use array_map to cast that thing and it's now working.. thanks all..:)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to cast them all first, then search. Like this:

```
$new_arr = array_map(function($piece){
    return (string) $piece;
}, $arr);

// then use in array
if(in_array('285078', $new_arr)) {
    echo 'exists';
} else {
    echo 'does not exists';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First, your array is not array of strings, it's array of objects.
If you can't change the structure of array try this:

```
foreach ($your_array as $item) {
    if (strval($item) == '25478') {
        echo 'found!';
        break;
    }
}
```

If you can change your array, add items to it like this:

```
$your_array[] = strval($appended_value);
```

After that you can use `in_array`.

Answer (score 1):

in_array is not recursive, it searches only on first level. 
and first level member of you array are SimpleXMLElement Objects, not an numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try with typecasting your array :-

```
$array =  (array) $yourarray;
if(in_array('285078',$arr))
    {
        echo 'yes';
    }
    else
    {
       echo "No";
    }
```

Comment: Casting array to array? Hmmmm

Comment: i think still not search

Comment: Will it not get typecast ?

Comment: yeah converting object to array?

Comment: yes, so that he gets only array and not aaray of objects